# Magento 2 - static content deploy make en_GB default

Tags: magento-2.1, static-content-deploy

Simple question, but can't seem to find anywhere online that explains it.

Using static content deploy, to generate the theme files like so:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Obviously once the theme is deployed and in developer mode, i don't need to do this again, but...

This deploys to **en_US** but my store is running under **en_GB** , is there a default way to deploy to en_GB inside of my theme or anywhere in-particular? or do i have to pass this through each time i want to do a *S:S:D*

If anyone knows if it can or cannot be done, that'd be a big help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a look into this myself in the past. It seems Magento sets the Default Language as a Constant inside the following class:

`Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand`

```
/**
 * Default language value
 */
const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE_VALUE = 'en_US';
```

It then references the constant when it prepares the deployable entities, inside `private function prepareDeployableEntities($filesUtil)`.

So without going into too much detail, maybe you could write a preference for your own class and set the constant to `en_GB`.

See the following for some good instructions on how to set a preference in M2:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Your extensions `etc/di.xml` would looks something like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Deploy\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand" type="Namespace\Module\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand" />
    </config>
```

Another option could be to redefine the argument for `staticContentDeployCommand` although I'm not too sure how this would work. Possibly just like below in your `etc/di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandListInterface">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="staticContentDeployCommand" xsi:type="object">Namespace\Module\Console\Command\DeployStaticContentCommand</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Hope this helps,

Josh

Comment: Massive help, exactly what i was looking for, thank you josh :)

Comment: You're welcome Andy, glad i could help!